# Docker container is unable to connect to port opened by another docker container

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I have two containers running: c1 and c2.

C1 is listening on port 2181 and
C2 is connecting to port 2181

Problem is C2 fails to connect to C1 on said port and I'm not sure why.

When I run the code that connects to C1 NOT in a container it works fine.  So I know C1 is running and the port is exposed correctly.  It just when I drop the application in it's own container then the port is not visible anymore.

I've tried lsof from within C2 and it is NOT listed, which makes sense to why it fails.

Any clues on where I need to look next would be appreciated.

I was using docker-compose so the containers should be in the same network group by default:

Here's my compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  c1:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - c2
  c2:
    image: jplock/zookeeper
    ports:
       - "2181:2181"
       - "2888:2888"
       - "3888:3888"
```

In C1, the initiator is using the URI localhost:2181

Comment: Show us your code? Not all of it, but enough to accurately reproduce the problem.  Specifically, what address are you using to connect to the second container?

Comment: Ahh good point, just read that you should use the name of the container listed in the compose file in place of the host name. I'm still referencing localhost.  I'll try that out and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks Larsks you helped me get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you come across this post this might help.

Using docker-compose, the containers get set a hostname matching the service alias in the docker compose file, see docs here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Modified quote to fit this use-case

> Each container can now look up the hostname (i.e c2) and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, c1 application code could connect to the URL //c2:2181.